# How to correctly place a return statement in a recursive method with if\else conditions

Tags: java, recursion, return

I'm writing recursive code that is build with if\else controlling the return statements. However when I compile, I get a 'missing return statement' because all of my returns are in the conditions. I'm adding 'fake' returns(to which the method should never reach) but I was wondering if there is a smarter solution.

for example:

```
    private static boolean compare(int[][] a, int i) {
     if (i == a.length - 1) {
      return true;
     } 
     else {
       if (calcLineSum(a[i], 0, 0) == calcLineSum(a[i + 1], 0, 0)){
         compare(a, i + 1);
       }
       else { 
        return false;
       }
     }
     return false; //<= = 'fake'
    }
    private static int calcLineSum(int[] a, int i, int sum) {
     if (i == a.length)
      return sum;
     else {
      sum = sum + a[i];
      calcLineSum(a, i + 1, sum);
     }
     return sum; //<= = 'fake'
    }
```

thank you very much for your input!

Comment: 1) format your code. 2) format your code. 3) if code is never supposed to reach there - throw an exception.

Comment: What makes you think your code will never reach those returns?  It _absolutely_ will.  `return` only exits that _one_ invocation of the method, not the whole recursive stack.

Comment: Not just formatting, but using braces on the `else` statement and not the `if` statement makes me cringe.

Answer (score 3):

I think if you replace `compare(a,i+1);` with `return compare(a,i+1);` and `calcLineSum(a,i+1,sum);` with `return calcLineSum(a,i+1,sum);` it should compile.

Every `if` and `else if` should be terminated with a `return`.

Comment: Thank you this has been an extremely useful advice! Can you please elaborate on of whats happening and what are the differences between just calling the method again to making a return statement? Thank you!

Comment: @roony exactly that. One calls the method and - ignores what it done. The other returns it.

Answer (score 2):

First off; indent your code properly and add braces to all of your conditions. It will seriously save you hours of debugging.

When its properly formatted its easy to spot the error:

```
private static boolean compare (int[][]a, int i)
{
    if(i==a.length-1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if(calcLineSum(a[i],0,0)==calcLineSum(a[i+1],0,0))
        {
            compare(a,i+1);
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false; <=='fake' return
}
```

You can clearly see the statement `compare(a,i+1);` is missing the `return`. Happy debugging!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you misunderstand `return`.  In your code

```
private static int calcLineSum (int[]a, int i, int sum)
{
    if(i==a.length)
        return sum; // only returns `sum` from this one invocation,
                    // *not* further up the recursive chain
    else {
        sum=sum+a[i];
        calcLineSum(a,i+1,sum);
        // your code is **still going** here; the `return` from
        // the recursive call didn't change anything
        // also note that `sum` hasn't actually changed here
        // sum is passed by value, and changes to it inside the recursive call
        // don't actually make any difference out here
    }
    return sum; // actually used
}
```

It looks like the correct implementation would be

```
private static int calcLineSum(int[] a, int i, int sum) {
  if (i == a.length) {
    return sum;
  } else {
    return calcLineSum(a, i+1, sum + a[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explantation. To clarify: when I do a return on the method call itself, once 'returned' it terminates also all other invocations? I've noticed this is whats happening in the debugging but I'm looking to understand the logic. Thanks again!

Comment: @roony: to clarify: that is exactly what _doesn't_ happen.  It _doesn't_ terminate all the other invocations.  In the debugger, it might look like that, because it's immediately doing another return on top of that, though.

Comment: So essentially all the previous invocations return the value of the last invocation- the one that reached the base case and ended the recursion?

Comment: Yes, as long as you actually put a return there.  If you didn't put a return there, it wouldn't return the value from the next level of the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
private static boolean compare (int[][]a, int i) {
    boolean result = false;

    if (i == a.length-1) {
        result = true;
    } else {
        if(calcLineSum(a[i],0,0) == calcLineSum(a[i+1],0,0)) {
                result = compare(a,i+1);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private static int calcLineSum (int[]a, int i, int sum) {
    int result = sum;

    if (i != a.length) {
        result = calcLineSum(a,i+1,sum+a[i]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that a method with a non-`void` return type **must** be guaranteed to return a value of that type.

Ignoring the specific code, the structure of your compare method is basically:

```
if() {
    return
} else {
    if () {
        // you don't return anything here, 
        // so the method might not do what you promised it would,
        // namely return a value
    } else {
        return
    }
}
```

If there is any way the method can run that won't return a value, the compiler will call you out on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursion:

```
private static int calcLineSum (int[]a, int i, int sum)
{
    if(i==a.length)
        return sum;
    else {
             sum=sum+a[i];
             calcLineSum(a,i+1,sum);
         }
    return sum; //<=='fake' return
}
```

You can do it pretty well like this:

```
private static int calcLineSum (int[]a, int i, int sum)
{
    if(i==a.length)
        return sum;
    sum=sum+a[i];
    calcLineSum(a,i+1,sum);
}
```

All I did was remove the *else*. If the first condition isn't met, with or withou the *else*, you will execute these two lines:

```
sum=sum+a[i];
calcLineSum(a,i+1,sum);
```

It simplifies your code too.

In addition, you can remove the line

```
sum=sum+a[i];
```

writing like this:

```
private static int calcLineSum (int[]a, int i, int sum)
{
    if(i==a.length)
        return sum;
    calcLineSum(a,i+1,sum+a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with out your last return statement (the ones you call fake); there are indeed condition that do not return anything;

For example in your first method if the following condition is satisfied nothing will be returned :

```
if (calcLineSum(a[i], 0, 0) == calcLineSum(a[i + 1], 0, 0))
```

similarly for your second method your else block do not return anything.

as a good coding practice please use { } arround if and else block.